# JMeter: Restful API Recording

Tags: rest, jmeter

I'm understand that need to use HTTP Test script to record web application that use Oauth authentication method. 
Questions:

> 1. How about the performance testing restful api with OAuth?
> 2. Why need correlate variables?
> 3. Why there are two request capture in jmx?
> 4. Any tutorial/video that i can follow to learn this topic?

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: how did you record the rest api calls using jmeter? or did you actually add each test case one by one?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really something you can record and replay, also there are several OAuth versions and within the bounds of one version there could be different authentication flows/algorithms.

There are:

1. [OAuth Core 1.0](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/)
2. [OAuth Core 1.0 Revision A](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/)
3. [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)

and depending on the OAuth version and your application configuration the flow will be different, but in case of OAuth 2.0 it would be something like:

[image]

You need to get [Access Token](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/) somehow by sending the same requests as browser does and add it as [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of [`Bearer`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) + Access Token using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

I don't think it is something you can successfully record and replay as the requests may include dynamic parameters like current timestamp and [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). If you need comprehensive assistance you will have to share the dump of requests/responses between your browser and the application under test (which is potentially big security hole)

Comment: I prefer to use OAuth 2.0. You mean i need to set the HTTP header manager with access token by using Bearer? Any sample test site?